# Grub with two hard drives

Tags: linux, partition, grub, dual-boot, boot-loader

I am trying to install Mint14 on my machine having two hard drives :

Samsung SSD PM830  SATA : 128 Gb  ( sda )   - Windows 7 (i want to keep this)

ST9500423AS ATA : 500 Gb          ( sdb )   - Install Linux

During installation i partitioned sdb into 150Gb and 350Gb and installed Linux on 350Gb partition.

During the process,I noticed that installer is running "grub install sdb".

But after reboot , Grub screeen doesnt appear and just boot up Windows.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIOS run bootstrap function which load MBR into memory which take MBR from First Sector of First HDD. So by running `grub install /dev/sdb` it will not check second HDD. you need to install on `grub install /dev/sda`  or you can Set sdb as primary HDD from CMOS Settings, then it will only boot Linux not windows.

Better is install Grub on sda , Grub is Powerful boot loader. it will keep windows boot load NTLDR into it which shows as "Other" in boot splash screen, you can have choice to select and boot OS.